# Invalid body indentation level (expecting an indentation level of at least 4)

Tags: php, heredoc, php-7.3

I just upgraded to PHP 7.3 and I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid body indentation level (expecting an indentation level of at least 4)
```

Here is the code:

```php
    $html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
    HTML test
</body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Comment: This might be better off as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: @miken32 didn't know about that, thanks. My only thought is that a lot of people may specifically be seeing this when upgrading to PHP 7.3 because of the syntax change. So it's very version specific

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by the new [flexible Heredoc syntaxes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes) in PHP 7.3.

In previous versions of PHP, the closing marker was not allowed to have indentation:

```php
    $string = <<<EOF
Hello
EOF;
```

As of PHP 7.3, the closing marker can be indented.

In this example, `EOF` is indented by 4 spaces. **The body of the string will also have 4 spaces stripped from the beginning of each line.**

```php
    $string = <<<EOF
    Hello
    EOF;
```

If the closing marker is indented further than any lines of the body, it will throw a Parse error:

```php
    $string = <<<EOF
  Hello
    EOF;
```

The reason for the error message is two-fold:

- The closing marker is indented further than 1 or more lines within the body

But perhaps more likely, for those upgrading to PHP 7.3:

- I've chosen a marker `HTML` which is also present within the string. Because of the flexible spacing now allowed, PHP was incorrectly detecting that the string had closed before I intended.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issue the indentation of the closing "output;" was an issue. Leave no space on the left.

```
    $html = <<<HTML
      <html>
       <body>
         HTML test
       </body>
      </html>
    OUTPUT;        // leave no space on the left before the code
    echo $html;
    }
```